# Ocultar objetos de un formulario con el botón de otro formulario C#

Tags: c#

tengo dos formularios abiertos al mismo tiempo, deseo que al presionar un botón del formulario 1 se puedan ocultar objetos del formulario2 como texboxt y label. intente crear un objeto del formulario 2 en mi formulario1

`formulario2 ocultar = new formulario2`

para usar la propiedad "Visible" e intentar ocultar los objetos

`ocultar.textbox1.Visible = false`

pero esta propiedad no me funciono :(, espero me puedan ayudar... soy novato en la programación, muchas gracias a todos los que me puedan ayudar!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! añade el codigo que intentaste. Esto es algo simple si los dos fomularios conocen al otro. Tene en cuenta, que los formularios son objetos como cualquier otro.

Comment: intente explicarlo de una mejor manera, espero me puedas ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Eso esta funcionando perfectamente... peroo sobre otro formulario, no sobre el que estas viendo, porque como te dije los formularios son objetos como cualquier otro. Y cuando haces ne, es otro nuevo, no el que esta en pantalla...

Comment: pero los dos están abiertos a la vez, los dos son visibles en la pantalla... conoces alguna otra manera de hacer lo que digo?

Comment: hola , tienes tu propiedad de textbox como publico? de ser asi utliza esto Form2 activar = new Form2();
             activar .textBox.Visible = false;

Comment: Hola Samuel, primero que todo gracias por tu ayuda, tengo los textbox como publico pero aun así al darle al botón no funciona el código.